# How to trim string with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to make Entity Framework automatically trim all strings before storing them in database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `IDbCommandInterceptor` to intercept all calls to the database.  Then trim any parameters being passed.

See [this article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx) for more details and especially how to register the interceptor.

```
class TrimCommandInterceptor: IDbCommandInterceptor
{
  public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> ctx)
  {
    foreach (var p in command.Parameters)
    {
       if (p.Value is string)
         p.Value = ((string) p.Value).Trim();
    }
  }

  // Add all the other interceptor methods
}
```

Comment: You must cast `p` to `DbParameter` to get access to the Value Property: `foreach (DbParameter p in command.Parameters)`